# swift Make UIImageView and UIView like one layer to make them animate together

Tags: swift, uiview, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view cell with many layers want to on them animate with each other like a one layer

this is two-layer one of them an image and the other is view

```
self.contentView.addSubview(ImageView)
self.contentView.addSubview(canvas)
canvas.frame = self.contentView.frame
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better to put the imageView and the canvas inside a container view and animate it

Comment: I made this its do better but still one of them at the end of animation move far the other one

Comment: this can't happen if both occupy the whole container frame

Comment: I have many layers with many UIPanGestureRecognizer this make more conflict on my cell  https://stackoverflow.com/users/5820010/sh-khan

Answer (score 0):

you can make frame of UIImageView center change with canvas in layoutsubview function or you can use constraintlayout to handling movement auto

```swift
self.contentView.addSubview(ImageView)
self.contentView.addSubview(canvas)

canvas.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        canvas.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.ImageView.topAnchor),
        canvas.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.ImageView.bottomAnchor),
        canvas.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.ImageView.leadingAnchor),
        canvas.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.ImageView.trailingAnchor)
])
```

Comment: you made my day https://stackoverflow.com/users/7804329/mohamed-farghal